# Read files in compile time

Tags: go, assets

I am developing a web server and I want to have all embedded on the same file.

I want to develop index.html, main.css, and scripts.js on separated files, but I want them to be read on compile time and embedded into the executable.

Is this posible with Go?

Comment: You likely want [`go generate`](https://blog.golang.org/generate), which is a pre-compilation step but allows for what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the //go:embed directive and the [embed](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/embed/) package in [Go 1.16](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.16)

Comment: If using an unreleased version of go (1.16 release expected Feb 2021) does not appeal then consider one of the existing solutions mentioned in the [embed design draft](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-embed.md) (along with go generate).

Comment: Note that Go 1.16 release candidate 1 is out today.